# VIM disable highlighting upon search deletion

Tags: vim, gvim, vimrc, gvimrc

I recently learned a new shortcut in VIM that I find extremely useful.

```
d/search_text
```

Which will delete everything up to, but not including, "search_text", from the current position.

However, the thing that is annoying is that this will highlight all occurrences of "search_text" after performing the operation.

Is there any way that I could disable the highlight feature when performing this operation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Type:

```
:noh
```

I need to add more to overcome the post size limit.

Comment: My current solution was to type
    `/sdgsah`
Or some other string that probably does not exist in the document.

But see, both of these solutions are annoying - turning things on and off. Or searching for something that does not exist, in my 'solution'.

Comment: `:noh` is more "correct", though I agree that it's a pain to type. That's why I have it mapped to a shortcut key. I have `map <F5> :nohls<CR>` in my `.vimrc`, but which key you use is up to you. I picked `<F5>` because I use this so much it made sense to pick a prominent, single key.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like overkill to mess with the 'highlightsearch' setting just for this delete operation, but you could.

```
:set nohls
d/search_text
:set hls
```

There are more complicated ways, but they would require writing a function, or grabbing input.

Answer (score 1):

I hate it so I leave `hlsearch` off (its default value) but have `set incsearch` in my `~/.vimrc`.

Matching is done incrementally, the first occurence is highlighted and goes back to normal upon hitting `<Return>`. It's incredibly clean and useful.

See `:help incsearch`.